# How to run multiple webservers inside docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3"

    services:
    consumerhub:
        container_name: consumerhub
        build: ./
        # command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        command: "bash -c 'python manage.py runserver react 0.0.0.0:8000 && npm start --prefix frontend/'"
        working_dir: /usr/src/consumerhub
        ports:
        - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
        - ./:/usr/src/consumerhub
```

Here i am tring to run two server inside docker-compose.
my backend is python and frontend is react.
When i am using "docker-compose up --build" it is only running python server but not running react server.

PLease have a look

Comment: aint you should be writing a seperate service for your react frontend?

Comment: Could You Please edit The file